# Regex pattern for single backslash

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match the below string. I am not able to get it right. Could someone please help?

```
string str = "test\tester";
            if (Regex.IsMatch(str, "/\\/"))
                MessageBox.Show("Match");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Not match");
```

I am wondering what is the Regex pattern I should use to get this matched.

Comment: You're not supposed to have `/` at the start and end.

Comment: Regex.IsMatch(str, @"\\")

Comment: @14V I get a "Not Match".

Comment: @Thomas it is not backslash char it is tab (`\t`). `test<TAB>ester` try this  `str = @"test\tester";`

Comment: @14V In my scenario, I cannot modify the value of str. It is something that comes from network.

Comment: @Thomas My Regex is correct. your string **does not** contain backslash. It is the tab char what you see in your string...

Comment: Thomas: I would bet money that your string is **not** "test\tester", but "test\\tester".

Comment: @Thomas: C# views `test\tester` as `test`, then a tab, then `ester`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you're way better of using `string.Contains()` from a performance point of view:

```
string str = @"test\tester"; //<- note the @

if (str.Contains("\\"))
    MessageBox.Show("Match");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Not match");
```

Be aware that in your test original string, you need to escape the `\` or `@` the string.

Comment: Much simpler than the other answers, and effective.  +1

Comment: I have this value (str) set from the network, and I am not able to escape the \. It is infact a user name in the format Domain\Username. I wanted to split this, but it never returns true for the condition str.Contains("\\").

Comment: +1 for the analysis, but -1 for the red herring.  Performance is not an issue until it becomes an issue.

Comment: @AlanMoore I disagree - specifically in this case, especially with regards to complexity, too. RegEx is far, far more complex solution than Contains, with many hidden performance gotchas.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use: `Regex.IsMatch(str, @".*\\.*")`

The double `\` is used to escape the backslash.

Comment: The regEx being passed to the method would be `.*\.*`, wouldn't it?  If so, this would match 0 or more `.`, which would ALWAYS return true.

Comment: Regardless of the `@`, the pattern would still fail as `.` matches any character including a slash.  This means `tester\\test` is just as valid as `tester\\\\\\\\\\\test`.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(@"test\\test", @".*\\.*") && Regex.IsMatch(@"test\\\\\\test", @".*\\.*") ? "Yes" : "No");` outputs yes.  It matches multiple backslashes.  You can simply write the pattern as `.*` as it would do the same thing.

Comment: @Kami - Not quite - it has to have at least one backslash to match, which is (I think) what the OP is asking.  True, it'll match more than one slash, but it won't match 0, hence it's not the same as `.*`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect **your test code is wrong**.

What you're testing:

```
string str = "test\tester";
```

But if what you're getting is "two parameters separated by a backslash", this should be

```
string str = "test\\tester";
```

This is because a backslash is represented in a constant as `\\`. Because `\t` happens to represent a tab character, your test code isn't throwing an error at compile time. If you did this:

```
string str = "mytest\mytester";
```

You'll get an error, because `\m` isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

The regex for a single backslash is `\\`.  If you want to make the string match exactly in C#, use the `@` operator:

`Regex.IsMatch(str, @".*\\.*")`

Alternatively, you can use C#'s escape characters:

`Regex.IsMatch(str, ".*\\\\.*")`

Comment: As has been mentioned before, this is because C# doesn't view "test\tester" as `test\tester` - it views it as `test` + tab + `ester`.